# Can't run Akeneo in Production

Tags: php, akeneo

I've decided to give Akeneo a try as it is exactly the product I need. I am unable to run the Production version of it, though. White screen of nothing shows up, with `status code of 500`. I've installed it according to the Installation tutorial on the Akeneo site, but all I am able to do, is access the `app_dev.php` (Development version of Akeneo). Why?

I have the right permissions set. `app/logs` show nothing related to production version.

I run Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7, MySQL 5.7.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see any logs in `app/logs`, you may have a fatal error.
You should check `/var/log/apache2/akeneo-pim_error.log` for any system or PHP error.

Regards,
JM

Comment: Well, thanks for the quick reply. I've checked error.log and it seems that I have a problem with APC cache. `FatalThrowableError: Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch()` in `Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php`. What can be done about this?

Comment: You can install the `apcu` extension or either use the array cache driver in `app/config/config_prod.yml`. If it's only to try Akeneo, the second solution will be enough.

Comment: How do I use array cache driver? I've searched the interwebz for some PHP 7 with APC info and found it all super confusing! There is no package to install, some say you have to enable it in php.ini somehow. Do you have any expertise there? Thanks!

Comment: Just change `apc` by `array` in the `config_prod.yml` file. (and do not forget to rate my comments if they are usefull ;) )

Comment: I've tried just that, and it didn't work for some reason. The error is still the same. Maybe some cache in between :) Sometimes, caches are just so painful. I will rate your comments, man! ;)

Comment: Maybe because you need to clear your cache ;) (back to Samir answer, lol)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115132/discussion-between-jmleroux-and-iss).

Answer (score 0):

A simple suggestion to start. Did you try to clear the symfony cache ?

```
app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

or even:

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Yes, I did, and it didn't help. It still returns code 500.